# PL/SQL, how to write single quote in a string/function?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In the Oracle PL/SQL I tried this way, it doesn't work:

```
....
sql_3 := sql_3 || q'[ upper(name_p) like Upper('%input_name%')]';
```

how to must use literal quoting? or the two quotes to denote a single quote?

Comment: try to add the single quote between two single quotes 
like this `'''%input_name%'''`

Comment: That does work - the [alternative quoting syntax is fine](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00218). Why do you think it doesn't? Are you getting an error, and if so are you sure it's from that line?

Comment: What is the exact error message you are getting? It is very unlikely to be caused by what you think. Unless   - what front-end are you using, and what version? (Such as SQL Developer, or Toad... - what product and version?) Older versions may not understand the alternative quote operator.

Comment: What does "It didn't work" mean?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to escape `'` and also remove q before second part of string. Square bracket in sql command will also make a problem if you're going to execute the command in Oracle

```
sql_3 := sql_3 || ' upper(name_p) like Upper(''%input_name%'')';
```

That's a bit weird but:

```
declare
  varr varchar2(100);
begin
  varr := 'aaa';
  varr := varr || q'[ upper(name_p) like Upper('%input_name%')]';
  dbms_output.put_line(varr);
end;
/
```

works on my machine.

Comment: The syntax in the question is valid - the `q` and square brackets are from [the alternative quoting mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00218) for string literals. What you have is also fine of course... but it shouldn't be necessary to modify what was shown.

Comment: that sentence not working for me, for that reason tried to use q´[...]

Comment: @AlexPoole My fault I haven't known the syntax. But in fact what is in question looks correct and should work.

Comment: Yep. It would really help if @rockerchain told us the error they are getting, from either statement... yours should work in any version, alternative quoting was added some time after 9.0, but was certainly in 10.1 onwards.

Comment: @rockerchain what version of Oracle it is?

Comment: @Kacper oracle 11g

Comment: @rockerchain so your query should work. Probably the error is somwhere else in the code. However if first option from my answer works use that one.

Comment: thanks @AlexPoole and Kacper , finally added one quote more and works well, i mean:     sql_3 := sql_3 || ' upper(name_p) like '||Upper('''%'||input_name||'%''');